# Why is pandas df.diff(2) different than df.diff().diff()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

According to Ender's [Applied Econometric Time Series](https://books.google.com.ar/books/about/Applied_Econometric_Time_Series.html?id=1bDCQgAACAAJ), the second difference of a variable `y` is defined as:
[image: double differencing]

Pandas provides the [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) function that receives "periods" as an argument. Nevertheless, `df.diff(2)` gives a different result than `df.diff().diff()`.

Code excerpt showing the above:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
       C.1   C.2    C.3     C.4     C.5   C.6
C.0
1990  16.0   6.0  256.0   216.0   65536  4352
1991  17.0   7.0  289.0   343.0  131072  5202
1992   6.0  -4.0   36.0   -64.0      64   252
1993   7.0  -3.0   49.0   -27.0     128   392
1994   8.0  -2.0   64.0    -8.0     256   576
1995  13.0   3.0  169.0    27.0    8192  2366
1996  10.0   0.5  100.0     0.5    1024  1100
1997  11.0   1.0  121.0     1.0    2048  1452
1998   4.0  -6.0   16.0  -216.0      16    80
1999   5.0  -5.0   25.0  -125.0      32   150
2000  18.0   8.0  324.0   512.0  262144  6156
2001   3.0  -7.0    9.0  -343.0       8    36
2002   0.5 -10.0    0.5 -1000.0      48    20
2003   1.0  -9.0    1.0  -729.0       2     2
2004  14.0   4.0  196.0    64.0   16384  2940
2005  15.0   5.0  225.0   125.0   32768  3600
2006  12.0   2.0  144.0     8.0    4096  1872
2007   9.0  -1.0   81.0    -1.0     512   810
2008   2.0  -8.0    4.0  -512.0       4    12
2009  19.0   9.0  361.0   729.0  524288  7220

In [9]: df.diff(2)
Out[9]:
       C.1   C.2    C.3     C.4       C.5     C.6
C.0
1990   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN       NaN     NaN
1991   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN       NaN     NaN
1992 -10.0 -10.0 -220.0  -280.0  -65472.0 -4100.0
1993 -10.0 -10.0 -240.0  -370.0 -130944.0 -4810.0
1994   2.0   2.0   28.0    56.0     192.0   324.0
1995   6.0   6.0  120.0    54.0    8064.0  1974.0
1996   2.0   2.5   36.0     8.5     768.0   524.0
1997  -2.0  -2.0  -48.0   -26.0   -6144.0  -914.0
1998  -6.0  -6.5  -84.0  -216.5   -1008.0 -1020.0
1999  -6.0  -6.0  -96.0  -126.0   -2016.0 -1302.0
2000  14.0  14.0  308.0   728.0  262128.0  6076.0
2001  -2.0  -2.0  -16.0  -218.0     -24.0  -114.0
2002 -17.5 -18.0 -323.5 -1512.0 -262096.0 -6136.0
2003  -2.0  -2.0   -8.0  -386.0      -6.0   -34.0
2004  13.5  14.0  195.5  1064.0   16336.0  2920.0
2005  14.0  14.0  224.0   854.0   32766.0  3598.0
2006  -2.0  -2.0  -52.0   -56.0  -12288.0 -1068.0
2007  -6.0  -6.0 -144.0  -126.0  -32256.0 -2790.0
2008 -10.0 -10.0 -140.0  -520.0   -4092.0 -1860.0
2009  10.0  10.0  280.0   730.0  523776.0  6410.0

In [10]: df.diff().diff()
Out[10]:
       C.1   C.2    C.3     C.4       C.5      C.6
C.0
1990   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN       NaN      NaN
1991   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN       NaN      NaN
1992 -12.0 -12.0 -286.0  -534.0 -196544.0  -5800.0
1993  12.0  12.0  266.0   444.0  131072.0   5090.0
1994   0.0   0.0    2.0   -18.0      64.0     44.0
1995   4.0   4.0   90.0    16.0    7808.0   1606.0
1996  -8.0  -7.5 -174.0   -61.5  -15104.0  -3056.0
1997   4.0   3.0   90.0    27.0    8192.0   1618.0
1998  -8.0  -7.5 -126.0  -217.5   -3056.0  -1724.0
1999   8.0   8.0  114.0   308.0    2048.0   1442.0
2000  12.0  12.0  290.0   546.0  262096.0   5936.0
2001 -28.0 -28.0 -614.0 -1492.0 -524248.0 -12126.0
2002  12.5  12.0  306.5   198.0  262176.0   6104.0
2003   3.0   4.0    9.0   928.0     -86.0     -2.0
2004  12.5  12.0  194.5   522.0   16428.0   2956.0
2005 -12.0 -12.0 -166.0  -732.0       2.0  -2278.0
2006  -4.0  -4.0 -110.0  -178.0  -45056.0  -2388.0
2007   0.0   0.0   18.0   108.0   25088.0    666.0
2008  -4.0  -4.0  -14.0  -502.0    3076.0    264.0
2009  24.0  24.0  434.0  1752.0  524792.0   8006.0

In [11]: df.diff(2) - df.diff().diff()
Out[11]:
       C.1   C.2    C.3     C.4       C.5      C.6
C.0
1990   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN       NaN      NaN
1991   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN       NaN      NaN
1992   2.0   2.0   66.0   254.0  131072.0   1700.0
1993 -22.0 -22.0 -506.0  -814.0 -262016.0  -9900.0
1994   2.0   2.0   26.0    74.0     128.0    280.0
1995   2.0   2.0   30.0    38.0     256.0    368.0
1996  10.0  10.0  210.0    70.0   15872.0   3580.0
1997  -6.0  -5.0 -138.0   -53.0  -14336.0  -2532.0
1998   2.0   1.0   42.0     1.0    2048.0    704.0
1999 -14.0 -14.0 -210.0  -434.0   -4064.0  -2744.0
2000   2.0   2.0   18.0   182.0      32.0    140.0
2001  26.0  26.0  598.0  1274.0  524224.0  12012.0
2002 -30.0 -30.0 -630.0 -1710.0 -524272.0 -12240.0
2003  -5.0  -6.0  -17.0 -1314.0      80.0    -32.0
2004   1.0   2.0    1.0   542.0     -92.0    -36.0
2005  26.0  26.0  390.0  1586.0   32764.0   5876.0
2006   2.0   2.0   58.0   122.0   32768.0   1320.0
2007  -6.0  -6.0 -162.0  -234.0  -57344.0  -3456.0
2008  -6.0  -6.0 -126.0   -18.0   -7168.0  -2124.0
2009 -14.0 -14.0 -154.0 -1022.0   -1016.0  -1596.0
```

Why are they different? Which one corresponds to the one defined in Ender's book?

Comment: `diff()` first argument is the `periods` which is not the second derivative..  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is precisely because

*Δ<sup>2</sup> y<sub>t</sub> = y<sub>t</sub> - 2 y<sub>t - 1</sub> + y<sub>t - 2</sub> ≠ y<sub>t</sub>  - y<sub>t - 2</sub>*.

The left hand side is `df.diff().diff()`, whereas the right hand side is `df.diff(2)`. For the difference in difference, you want the left hand side.

Comment: Nice and succinct answer, I like this

Answer (score 5):

Consider;

```
df
a
b
c
d
```

`df.diff()` is

```
NaN
b - a
c - b
d - c
```

`df.diff(2)` is

```
NaN
NaN
c - a
d - b
```

`df.diff().diff()` is

```
NaN
NaN
(c - b) - (b - a) = c - 2b + a
(d - c) - (c - b) = d - 2c + b
```

They're not the same, mathematically.

Comment: I think the concrete example is great. Didn't think of it.

Comment: @AmiTavory this is one of those times I really wish OP could accept multiple answers :o)

Comment: @AmiTavory, I think both answers are great. One is the formal definition and the other is an example. I'm choosing the formal definition one and if someone needs an example they can check the example answer below. I wish both answers could be joined into one.

Comment: @Alechan No problem, accept Ami's please, it is well worth it... also, egad, there was a bug in the last one, which I fixed